# Convert datetime to format in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

How could I convert the following date string into accepted format in ruby on rails

```
Thu, Aug 25 12:00 AM
```

Also I want  global solution that could also go with the following formats including the above given:

```
August 25 2016
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if variable is Time or Date class

`[variable].strftime("%a, %B %d %T:%s %P")`

`[variable].strftime("%B %d %Y")`

if you want to see more format directives

check it out http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Answer (score 0):

The most important one is the `config.time_zone` configuration in your `config/application.rb` file. `ActiveRecord` will help you convert from and to (which the documentation fails to explain) `UTC` and the time zone of your choice. This means that if all you’re doing is having users post times through a form and use `Active Record` to persist it you’re good to go.

```
Date.today
 => Thu, 25 Aug 2016
```

**PARSING**

When parsing time information it’s important to never do it without specifying the `time zone`. The best way to do this is to use `Time.zone.parse` (which will use the time zone specified in `config.time_zone`) instead of just `Time.parse` (which will use the computer’s time zone).

Hope This help you!

Comment: Actually @VKatz all these datetime I'm receiving is in PDT format... I just wanted to store it into the database but after parsing it to the format +0000 or somehow appending the PDT time format -0700 into the original string.... Example: Thu, Aug 25 03:00 PM to be converted to Thu, Aug 25 22:00:00 +0000 or Thu, Aug 25 15:00 -0700

Comment: Okey So you mean to say while saving records there is no problem but while retrieving it is giving unexpected result set Right?